# DBUNIT not inserting in order from XML file

Tags: java, xml, database, oracle, dbunit

So I've been using dbunit to insert rows to a table in oracle sql developer.
My xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "./test/testdata/c21tsc.dtd">
<dataset>
<TCODEDTL   CD_NO="304"
   ID_NO="1"
   TIME_DELIV="8:00"
 />
 <TCODEDTL  CD_NO="304"
   ID_NO="2"
   TIME_DELIV="10:00"
/>
<TCODEDTL CD_NO="304"
   ID_NO="3"
   TIME_DELIV="11:00"
/>
<TCODEDTL CD_NO="304"
  ID_NO="error_test"
  TIME_DELIV="12:00"
 />
</dataset>
```

And my actual codes for insertion. This is working and rows are inserted to oracle.

```
//Fetching Oracle connection
connection = getConnection();

//Storing rows to be added from XML file to dataset
IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileReader("filepath"));;

// Clean Insert
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
```

but when I checked the oracle DB, the order was not retained which is not what I intended to achieve. I want to insert it the way I arranged the rows in the xml file.

Here is the actual oracle DB

```
-----------------------------------
| CD_NO   | ID_NO    |  TIME_DELIV |
------------------------------------
| 304     |    3     |    11:00    |
------------------------------------
| 304     |error_test|    12:00    |
------------------------------------
| 304     |    1     |     8:00    |
------------------------------------
| 304     |    2     |    10:00    |
------------------------------------
```

I tried checking the orders using the ITable and the order were not changed.

```
        //Storing rows to be added from XML file to dataset
        IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileReader("filepath"));;

        //Check row order
        ITable expectedTable = dataSet.getTable("TARGET_TABLE");
        for(int x=0; x < expectedTable.getRowCount(); x++){
            System.out.println(expectedTable.getValue(x, "ID_NO"));
        }
```

It prints...

```
1
2
3
error_test
```

So I assumed that the code DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet); is the one causing the rows to be unordered. I've been searching on how to fix this but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?  A db table's contents have no inherent ordering.  You need to include an ORDER BY clause  in your select statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. Yes, that is the work-around we did, we put ORDER BY clause for the latter part of our code. But without it, it is following the order on how the dbunit inserted the dataset in the database. I am just curious if it's possible to set the original order from the xml file upon executing it through CLEAN_INSERT.

Comment: Enabling org.dbunit debug logging will show the processing and inserts.  Perhaps will show something interesting and can update the question with relevant findings.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I will check this.